# Middle mouse button does not move the user perspective

Tags: 3d-view, navigation

I'm new to Blender and 2.81 is way too different.

I was using the press & hold middle button normally, tried to create a new plane with PBR materials (previously prepared with Youtube tutorials).

Then I typed x, y & z many times to cycle lock/unlock view. No do.

Tried unchecking the transform options "origins" & "locations", nothing.

Tried loading the factory settings, still can't move around with the middle mouse button. Auto perspective unchecked as well.

Just noticed the screen zooms in to the object when pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>

[Same problem 3 years ago.](https://www.reddit.com/r/blender/comments/4splqt/help_middle_mouse_button_will_not_rotate_camera/) 
[image]

Comment: Is *emulate 3 button mouse* unchecked in the user preferences?

Comment: It is unchecked, did not work. Thanks for your support.

Comment: I just tried to check that little magic box and now it works with Alt + LMB

Comment: I know it is not the exact solution BUT it works and now I can finish my logo which is what I wanted.

Thanks to Nate_Sycro27 for the idea, turning Emulate 3 button mouse enables you to move the user perspective pressing Alt + LMB

Path to enable this option on Blender 2.81.16: 

Edit>Preferences>Input>Mouse>Emulate 3 Button Mouse

Right [here](https://imgur.com/gallery/9iYcX7o "Emulate 3 Button Mouse")!

Comment: If the middle button is not working, that is probably the mouse, not Blender.

Comment: The mouse works perfectly. The middle button as well. It was working fine and suddenly it stoped working. I read a lot of people with the same issue over the years. I even included an example with the same situation 3 years ago, it's not mouse.

Answer (score 0):

Check your keymap preferences. Click the edit drop down from the top of the window, click preferences at the very bottom, and navigate to where I am in the attached picture. Is rotate mapped to your middle mouse button? [image]

Comment: Thanks for your support, just checked my settings and they are same as yours.

Comment: You are welcome. Your mouse is in the 3D viewport when you are trying to rotate of course, correct? Have you tried restarting the program?

Comment: If by restarting the software you mean uninstall and installing again... I'm leaving it as my last option... will try it next week. Thanks again man!